# How to fetch the next 20 records from the database for the same search criteria?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a requirement to **fetch 20 records at a time** from the database(The database contains atleast 100 records) when the user clicks on **search** button. When the user clicks the **next page** button, **the next 20 records** should be fetched for the **same search** criteria.How can i implement that in my asp.net application?

Please help.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12338/Using-ROW_NUMBER-to-paginate-your-data-with-SQL-Se

Comment: Simply you fetch all data and pass it to gridview or repeater which will do pagination for you.Performance will also be good when using pagination.These are dedicated controls.Dont mess yourself with sqlqueries.

Comment: Am assuming you have gridview to display your data, if yes then you can set  `pagesize="20"` on your gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all data in your Database using Select fldName From TableName Where "Your Condition" is applied pass it to asp.net Gridview and apply Paging for tutorials Try this

[Asp.Net PAGING](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/410733/Custom-paging-with-ASP-NET-GridView)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataList control and implement Paging property with PageSize  = 20.

http://www.dotnetbull.com/2012/08/paging-in-datalist-in-aspnet.html

Answer (score 0):

Here you take a hidden field for remembering search criteria, page number, starting row and last row number.

In SQL, write a query like this:

```
Select * from (Select *, Row_number()over (order by id) as Row from QatarStockMarket) T
Where T.Row Between 30 and 40
```

Here, 20 -> start row number and 40 -> last row number.

Now do change a hidden field value. Start at row 40 and end at row 60 for the next page.