# adding 'next' link to web application

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have been able to limit the number of data to send to the application however I need help setting up the application to show the fetch next button.

data retrieval code - I am using show only 2 rows because I have a small amount of data in the test database

```
 <WebMethod(Description:="Retrieve members of a Client List"), SoapHeader("MessageSoapHeader", direction:=SoapHeaderDirection.In)> _
Public Function GetClientListMembers() As DataSet
    Dim RS As SqlDataReader

    RS = objApp.ConnectUser(MessageSoapHeader.UID, MessageSoapHeader.PWD, MessageSoapHeader.Campaign, MessageSoapHeader.Keyword, LocalCommon.apSOAPAdvanced)
    RS.Close()
    If objApp.ClassErrorsCount > 0 Then
        objApp.DB.Close()
        Dim NX As New Exception
        LLIB.ThrowSOAPException(objApp.Errors(1).Number, NX, objApp.DB, objApp.Errors(1).ErrorType, objApp.Errors(1).Description)
        GetClientListMembers = New DataSet
        Exit Function
    End If
    LLIB.FunctionCount(objApp, "GetClientListMembers") 'This must be placed after the close of RS

    GetClientListMembers = LLIB.GetDataSet("SELECT CellNumber,Carrier,Keyword, dbo.fn_ToUTC(ActualOptInDate) AS ActualOptInDate FROM Optins WHERE ShortCode='" & objApp.ShortCode & "' AND Keyword='" & objApp.Keyword & "' AND OptInState=2 ORDER BY CellNumber ASC Offset 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY", objApp)
    GetClientListMembers.Tables(0).TableName = "Cell Numbers"
    LLIB.RecordRowTransfer(GetClientListMembers.Tables(0).Rows.Count, LLIB.RowTransferDirection.ToClient, objApp)
    'Now get the email stuff
    LLIB.AddDataTable(GetClientListMembers, "Email Addresses", "SELECT EmailAddress,Keyword, dbo.fn_ToUTC(ActualOptInDate) AS ActualOptInDate FROM EmailOptins WHERE ShortCode='" & objApp.ShortCode & "' AND Keyword='" & objApp.Keyword & "' AND OptInState=2 ORDER BY EmailAddress", objApp)

    If GetClientListMembers.Tables.Count > 1 Then LLIB.RecordRowTransfer(GetClientListMembers.Tables(1).Rows.Count, LLIB.RowTransferDirection.ToClient, objApp)

    objApp.DB.Close()
End Function
```

The user view (where I need to add the 'next' link is

```
  Private Sub DisplayDS(ByRef ThisDS As DataSet, ByVal tblNumber As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    Me.txtDisplay.Text = ThisDS.ToString
    Me.comboDSTables.Items.Clear()
    For i = 0 To ThisDS.Tables.Count - 1
        Me.comboDSTables.Items.Add(i.ToString & "_" & ThisDS.Tables(i).TableName)
    Next
    Me.comboDSTables.SelectedIndex = tblNumber
    Me.lblNumberOfTables.Text = ThisDS.Tables.Count
    Dim myBindingSource As BindingSource = New BindingSource
    myBindingSource.DataSource = ThisDS.Tables(tblNumber)
    Me.AdvDataGrid.DataSource = myBindingSource
End Sub
```

The 'click' or button code is

```
    'Private Sub cmdDeleteSLMembersDifferential_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdDeleteSLMembersDifferential.Click
'    Dim xmlNodeResult As Xml.XmlNode
'    LoadHeader()
'    Try
'        xmlNodeResult = AdvServer.DeleteSendListMembersDifferential(Me.txtListName.Text, TestDB())
'    Catch SoapEx As Exception
'        MsgBox(SoapEx.Message)
'        Exit Sub
'    End Try
'    Me.txtDisplay.Text = xmlNodeResult.OuterXml
'End Sub

Private Sub cmdSendToList_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSendToList.Click
    Dim xmlNodeResult As Xml.XmlNode, ThisTime As Date
    LoadHeader()
    If Me.chkDelay.Checked Then
        If IsDate(Me.txtDelayTime.Text) Then
            ThisTime = CDate(Me.txtDelayTime.Text)
            ThisTime = ThisTime.ToUniversalTime 'Input is in local time.
        Else
            MsgBox("Delay set but Delay Time is not a date")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        ThisTime = Now()
    End If
    Try
        xmlNodeResult = AdvServer.SendToSendList(Me.txtListName.Text, Me.txtMsg.Text, Me.chkDelay.Checked, ThisTime)
    Catch SoapEx As Exception
        MsgBox(SoapEx.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    Me.txtDisplay.Text = xmlNodeResult.OuterXml
End Sub
```

ANY help is much appreciated - I have been working on this for about a week and it is escaping me!

Thank you!

Comment: Portlight, sorry, I am confused. Why not use pagination of the gridview. Please set me on the right track to help you, I fear I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: I was under the impression that pagination could not be used and the person I am working with suggested using 'Offset 100 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY' to the query - my issue with this it seems to be the query linked to the 'next' button - not the original button click - I really am just lost - ANY assistance would be helpful

Comment: Hi, here is a link that discusses your solution. I hope this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566138/how-to-fetch-the-next-20-records-from-the-database-for-the-same-search-criteria

Comment: levi - Would you be willing to look at this code a little more in depth with me. I just have some questions that are confusing me.

Comment: Yeah, post what you got. I'll help as much as I can, and eventually one of the gurus will step in and set up straight.

Comment: unfortunately what I have is posted -

Comment: What is that is confusing you? I would like to see how your setting up your grid. So far, we only see the code behind. Can you post the Asp page?

Comment: There are no asp pages in the application. It is all vb

Comment: Portlight, here is an article for you. http://shahanayyub.wordpress.com/2014/03/30/how-to-load-large-dataset-in-datagridview/